# Android Studio duplicate Version Control

Tags: android-studio

I am creating a new  project with Blank Activity in Android Studio.

Then VCS > Enable Version Control Integration > Git > OK.

After that I am closing the project and immediately I am opening it.

I am opening  Setting > Version Control and it turns out that settings duplicate.

If I close and open the project again, one more backup line appears.  And the quantity of such duplicating lines increases with every start.

Please, could you explain me, if  it is normal or I  do something wrong? Thanks a lot for you response.

http://hsto.org/files/806/992/9a6/8069929a60724887b55805b4fd6868e9.png